# How to feed search output from one query as a value to another query

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume a classroom database. It has two tables (stuDB and regDB):

- stuDB contains columns age, dob, rollnum. rollnum are unique numerics (1 to 100) assigned to each student, rest of the attributes (age, DOB) are not unique.
  Search query1:
  *Select age, DOB, rollnum from db1.stuDB where age='x'* <--- this returns a table of all x year old students with their age, DOB and unique rollnum.
- regDB contains studentname, fathername, regno. Note that regno is unique numeric, equal to his rollnum for each student. i.e. regno=rollnum for all students.
  Search query2:
  *Select fathername, mothername, childage, regno from db1.regDB where regno='1'*

I first run query1, determine value of rollnum, feed result of rollnum as regno manually into query2. Thus I have to run query 2 manually for each student.

I want to somehow club the two queries and show the result as a single search result showing all of it: *studentname, fathername, regno, fathername, mothername, childage, regno* at once, for my search criterion age=8.

In other words, build result of query1, feed the result of rollnum as regno into query2 and show combined result for both queries.

Can that be done? I have no knowledge of SQL so need some help here.

Hint:
The two queries can be joined using following:

SELECT * FROM (Select age, DOB, rollnum from db1.stuDB where age='x') CROSS JOIN (Select fathername, mothername, childage, regno from db1.regDB where **regno=*'1'***). Somehow, I want to feed output of ***rollnum*** from first half of this query as ***regno*** to second half of this query, automatically.

Comment: as a suggestion, you should call your objects with intuitive names. eg. stuDB is a table ( not a database ) and maybe could be called student ( assuming thats what it stores )

Comment: `Can that be done?`. yes it can - please post the output from show create table stuDB ( and same for regDB ) some sample data and desired output

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response. I got it working using Join On.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it resolved:

*SELECT age, DOB, rollnum, fathername, mothername, childage, regno 
From db1.stuDB 
Join db1.regDB 
ON db1.regDB.regno = rollnum
WHERE (age = 'x')*

*WHERE() can be just any search criterion I wish to use.

Thanks amdixon. Of course, this was only an example. My actual database is completely different has nothing to do with a school.

Comment: in general it helps for others to be able to replicate your issue ( with sample data, structure etc. ). good job on solving the problem though